# Jekyll using .htaccess locally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jekyll

I have a jekyll website that I am building locally. It has .htaccess file. My problem is when I `jekyll serve` and access website locally .htaccess rule for redirecting to 404 page does not work. If I upload the content _site folder to my hosting a wrong url will lead me to my custom 404 page. How can I start using .htaccess file locally?

The content of my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll server is **WEBrick** in not **apache** so `.htaccess` directives will not work.

Locally you can test by :

- doing a `jekyll serve` ans see if your 404.html is responding
- setting a local apache vhost to your `_site` folder an try to get a 404 by introducing a wrong url.